# recursively run script on each file in a directory and pipe each output to new file

Tags: recursion, find, markdown

I'm trying to convert every `.markdown` file in `~/notes/` (and below) to html, using the native `Markdown.pl --html4tags` script. However, `Markdown.pl` prints the html to stout, meaning that to convert `test.markdown` to `test.html`, I need to run: `Markdown.pl --html4tags test.markdown > test.html`.

I'm stuck in figuring out how to incorporate piping into a recursive `find -exec` or `find ... | xargs` function. The best I've come up with is:

```
for i in `find ~/notes/ -type f -name "*.markdown"` ; do
  Markdown.pl --html4tags $i > ${i}.html ;
done
```

It successfully converts every `.markdown` file into html, but of course it looks like `test.markdown.html` instead of `test.html`.

So basically, I need to be doing something like converting `${i}.markdown` into `${i}.html`, but I can't figure out how to encode that in the function. Thanks for any help.

**edit:** I figured out a way to fix the above script, using `basename` (which I just discovered):

```
for i in `find ~/notes/ -type f -name "*.markdown"` ; do
  Markdown.pl --html4tags $i > `basename $i .markdown`.html ;
done
```

This basically converts every `.markdown` file into html while also stripping the `.markdown` extension and then adding a `.html` extension.

I'd be curious to know if there are better ways of doing this, e.g., using `find -exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boom!

```bsh
find ~/notes/ -name '*.markdown' | while read line
do
    Markdown.pl --html4tags $line > ${line/.markdown/.html}
done
```